# Logstash Ruby Code to calculate average of array values

Tags: ruby, logstash

For SNMP CPU utilization I am getting data in the below format -

```
"cpmCPUTotalTable": [
      {
        "1.1.23": 0,
        "1.1.4": 11,
        "1.1.10": 12,
        "1.1.16": 0,
        "1.1.2": 1000,
        "1.1.12": 1555064,
        "1.1.19": 0,
        "1.1.22": 0,
        "1.1.14": 221420,
        "index": "1000",
        "1.1.11": 0,
        "1.1.9": 5,
        "1.1.21": 0,
        "1.1.18": 0,
        "1.1.5": 10,
        "1.1.15": 1734314400,
        "1.1.3": 12,
        "1.1.13": 2376240,
        "1.1.6": 12,
        "1.1.20": 0,
        "1.1.17": 0,
        "1.1.8": 10,
        "1.1.7": 11
      },
      {
        "1.1.23": 0,
        "1.1.4": 2,
        "1.1.10": 2,
        "1.1.16": 0,
        "1.1.2": 2000,
        "1.1.12": 1537672,
        "1.1.19": 0,
        "1.1.22": 0,
        "1.1.14": 221420,
        "index": "2000",
        "1.1.11": 0,
        "1.1.9": 5,
        "1.1.21": 0,
        "1.1.18": 0,
        "1.1.5": 2,
        "1.1.15": 1752823768,
        "1.1.3": 2,
        "1.1.13": 2393632,
        "1.1.6": 2,
        "1.1.20": 0,
        "1.1.17": 0,
        "1.1.8": 2,
        "1.1.7": 2
      },
      {
        "1.1.23": 0,
        "1.1.4": 2,
        "1.1.10": 1,
        "1.1.16": 0,
        "1.1.2": 3000,
        "1.1.12": 1191980,
        "1.1.19": 0,
        "1.1.22": 0,
        "1.1.14": 221420,
        "index": "3000",
        "1.1.11": 0,
        "1.1.9": 5,
        "1.1.21": 0,
        "1.1.18": 0,
        "1.1.5": 1,
        "1.1.15": 2013293636,
        "1.1.3": 1,
        "1.1.13": 2739324,
        "1.1.6": 1,
        "1.1.20": 0,
        "1.1.17": 0,
        "1.1.8": 1,
        "1.1.7": 2
      }
    ]
```

Now, I need to calculate the average for values of "1.1.8" in Logstash config using Ruby code. For  example here my output should be like - ((10+2+1)/3 = 4.3).

I am very new to logstash and ruby and stuck here. It would be a great help if anyone can give solution or suggestion on the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all this output is a hash and, for example, is stored in a variable `data`, the solution could be:

```
values = data[:cpmCPUTotalTable].map { |data_set| data_set[:"1.1.8"] }
average = values.sum(0.0) / values.count
```

Or shorter and prettier one-line solution by [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland)
:

```
data[:cpmCPUTotalTable].sum { |data_set| data_set[:"1.1.8"] }.fdiv(data[:cpmCPUTotalTable].size)
```

Comment: There's no need to produce a temporary array: `data[:cpmCPUTotalTable].sum { |data_set| data_set[:"1.1.8"] }.fdiv(data[:cpmCPUTotalTable].size)`. I prefer using [Numeric#fdiv](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Numeric.html#method-i-fdiv) to explicitly tell the reader I want a floating point result. Consider editing your answer.